# How can I make that my virtual machine reach internet via bridge on dedicated eth card

Tags: kvm, bridge

I've made a kvm virtual machine on a server which have to eth cards.
eno1 is the card that bring traffic to the server with IP 192.168.14.10
eno2 is the card I want to use has bridge for my vm, so I do that :
in etc/network/interface

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    address 192.168.14.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.14.1
    up route add -net 192.168.14.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.14.1
    down route del -net 192.168.14.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.14.1


auto br0
    iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.14.15
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    bridge_stp on
    bridge_fd 5
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

for my network

```
virsh net-list --all
    bridged-network   active   yes         yes
```

and the network:

````
<network>
  <name>bridged-network</name>
  <uuid>886a71d6-1840-4812-9473-9e85d0ecc92d</uuid>
  <forward mode='bridge'/>
  <bridge name='br0'/>
</network>```

my vm conf :
````

```
on the server route:<br>
```

192.168.14.0    192.168.14.1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eno1
192.168.14.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
192.168.14.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0

```
run/network/interface.d/ enp1s0 on the VM :<br>
```

auto enp1s0
allow-hotplug enp1s0

iface enp1s0 inet static
address 192.168.14.21
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.14.1

```
i have also done :<br>
```

vim /etc/sysctl.conf

net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0

net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0

net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0

```
But nothing work if i ping the server from my vm  nothing appen
if i ping my vm from the server nothing to
When i say nothing, i dont have network unreachabe or evry thing else i juste have nothing
ans i dont have internet accès from my vm.

I dont know what to do can some one help?\`
```